# Granting Write Permissions on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami, filezilla

when I connect with FileZilla to EC2 and when I try to edit and save a file, I get this error:

```
templates/user_memebership_profile.php: open for write: permission denied
Error: File transfer failed
```

What do I need to do to be able to edit and save files with FileZilla (or if you know a more convenient tool)?

Admittedly, I am not an infra expert. For this reason, I'd appreciate very much precise (if possible step-by-step) instructions on how to clear the cache.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Update permission using `sudo chmod +rwx file or directory`
2. or get owenership of file using `sudo chown file`

Comment: probably because the user you're using with FileZilla doesn't own the files you're attempting to copy

Comment: @KaushikThakkar: not sure how I can do that with FileZilla. can you please explain?

Comment: @erik258: I am not an infra. expert. Do you have any idea (and precise instructions) on how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: First thing, if you have admins or something taking care of this server for you, you need to talk to them.  They are the ones who likely control your permissions and may have methods of managing the website content.  Your methodology is very basic and most dev teams are doing something more sophisticated than directly uploading files after local edits.

Comment: Agree with @erik258. Also in FileZill, you can try by clicking on FileName, you will get option to change permission, that might work for you.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @KaushikThakkar: Thanks for your reply and suggestion. When I right click on the file, I see this: https://prnt.sc/AGHqsoVf91vK The only option is to make "write" as public permission, but I am not sure if that's the best idea. What are your thoughts?

Comment: This is not the best idea but yes for time being we can use and get work done. And reset the permission. The only best way is to ask your server administrator to give needful permission to update and create of files/directory.

Answer (score -1):

This solved the issue:

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/wordpress
sudo find /opt/bitnami/wordpress -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find /opt/bitnami/wordpress -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /bitnami/wordpress
sudo find /bitnami/wordpress -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find /bitnami/wordpress -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chmod 640 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php
```